# Prove that if $A$ is a non-(Lebesgue)measurable set and $B⋂A=∅$, show that $A⋃B$ is non-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is the following,

> Prove that if $A$ is a non-measurable set and $B⋂A=∅$, show that $A⋃B$ is non-measurable.

If $B$ is measurable, then it is obvious since assuming $A\bigcup B$ measurable will lead to $A$ is measurable. But how to show the claim holds when $B$ is non-measurable? Thank you!

Comment: Consider the characteristic function of $A \cup B$ and use the definition of measurability of functions.

Comment: Note that above comment applies to $\mathbb R$, though, as triple-sec notes, not in general measure spaces.

Comment: Not true in $\mathbb R$ either.  Try $B = A^c$ (i.e. the complement of $A$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This claim is *not* true.

Let $X\equiv\{1,2\}$ and consider the indiscrete $\sigma$-algebra on $X$: $\Sigma\equiv\{\varnothing, X\}$. Let $A\equiv\{1\}$ and $B\equiv\{2\}$. Then, $A$ and $B$ are non-measurable disjoint sets, but their union, $X$, is measurable.

Comment: @Tony Take any subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ that is not Lebesgue-measurable. Then, $B\equiv[0,1]\setminus A$ is not Lebesuge-measurable, either (if $B$ were measurable, then $A=[0,1]\cap B^c$ would be measurable, too). Clearly, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. But $A\cup B=[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you! So the claim only holds when $B$ is measurable.

Comment: @Tony Yes. Suppose that $A$ is not measurable, $B$ is, and $A\cap B=\varnothing$. Then, $C\equiv A\cup B$ is not measurable. To see this, note that if $C$ were measurable, then $A=C\cap B^c$ would be measurable, too (given $B$ and $B^c$ being measurable), which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Tony: My bad, I did assume $B$ was measurable. I will edit that in.

Comment: @Gary. That's ok. Thank you :) I am a beginner and you guys helped me a lot these days!

Answer (score 3):

This is not true (in any measurable space).

If $X$ is a set endowed with a $\sigma$-algebra $\cal{B}$ and $A$ is not measurable (i.e., $A\not\in\cal{B}$), then $X\setminus A$ is also not measurable. But $A\cup(X\setminus A)=X$ is measurable.

Answer (score 2):

This is true in the Real line ( and I think it extnds to $\mathbb R^n$ )EDIT: assuming $B$ is measurable and d(A,B)>0.
Let $C:= A \cup B $ and consider $\chi_C$. Now, assume wlog that we can separate $A,B$ by open sets, i.e., there is a set $V$ with $A \subset V$ and $V \cap B $ is empty. Then consider $(\chi_C (W))^{-1}=A$.

Comment: That $A$ and $B$ are disjoint doesn't imply that $d(A,B)>0$, nor that they can be separated by open sets!

Comment: @triple_sec: I know, I m saying that _if_ $d(A,B)>0$ then the result holds.And I think this is equivalent to the separating open set condition; a sort of reverseMathmatics to make the statement be true.

Comment: Fair enough, I now see you're _assuming_ it.

Comment: @triple_sec : How about getting rid of the Kouric?

Comment: Downvoter: Any reasons for downvote after edit? I did make implicit assumptions, but I edit it in the new conditions.

Comment: Kouric? (For the record, the downvote was not by me.)

Comment: @triple_sec: Sorry, it is a South Park thing, yes, the downvote. I wish people asked for a clarification first and then, if they are not satisfied, _then_ they could downvote.

Comment: I didn't see that episode. However, you're getting a Toshiba Handybook in the form of an upvote. :-)

Comment: @triple_sec: Thanks :) .